# Which characterset do i use for North American Phonetic in Oracle 12c and SQL Server 2016

Tags: oracle, special-characters, oracle12c, sql-server-2016

I have a requirement where DB Oracle 12c and SQL 2016 should accept using the North American Phonetic (NAPA) characters like **šxʷməθkʷəy̓əmasəm** and **hən̓q̓əmin̓əm̓**

which characterset would be ideal one

my current characterset is
Oracle (WE8MSWIN1252)
SQL (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Found that AL32UTF8 chracterset accomadates Nort American Phonetic (NAPA) characters